# Как задать размер с клавиатуры?

Tags: java, массивы, scanner

Есть класс содержащий массив и методы работы с ним, как задать его размер с клавиатуры?

```
public class DynamicArray {
    public static String[] array = new String[3];
    public int size = 0;

    public String get(int i) {
        return array[i];
    }

    public void add(String s) {

        if(array.length <= size) {
            String[] temp = array;
            array = new String[size+1];

            for(int i = 0; i < temp.length; i++) {
                array[i] = temp[i];
            }
        }
        array[size] = s;
        size++;
    }

    public void remove(int i) {
        for (int k = i; k < size - 1; k++)
            array[k] = array[k + 1];
        size--;
    }

    public int size() {
        return size;
    }

    public void state() {
        for (int i = 0; i < array.length; i++) {
            System.out.print(array[i] + " ");
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        DynamicArray array = new DynamicArray();
        boolean exit = true;

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        do {
            System.out.println("Choose an option:");
            System.out.println("1. Add element");
            System.out.println("2. Remove element");
            System.out.println("3. Show array size");
            System.out.println("4. Show array");
            System.out.println("5. Show element in array");

            int option = sc.nextInt();

            switch(option) {
                case 1:
                    System.out.println("Enter element to add");
                    array.add(sc.next());
                    System.out.println("Now array looks like: ");
                    array.state();
                    break;

                case 2:
                    System.out.println("Choose element index to remove");
                    array.remove(sc.nextInt());
                    System.out.println("Now array look like: ");
                    array.state();
                    break;

                case 3:
                    System.out.println("Array size is" + array.size());
                    break;

                case 4:
                    System.out.println("Now array looks like: ");
                    array.state();
                    break;

                case 6:
                    System.out.println("Enter the index of array");
                    array.get(sc.nextInt());
                    break;

                default:
                    System.out.println("Unknown operation");
                    break;

            }
            System.out.println("Enter 1 to continue, 0 to exit the application");
            option = sc.nextInt();
            if (option == 0) exit = false;

        } while(exit);

    }
}
```

Comment: добавить свою опцию в switch-case в которой будет производится инициализация переменной array

Answer (score 0):

Создайте конструктор, принимающий на вход размер массива:

```
public class DynamicArray {
    private String[] array; //массив array не должен быть static - иначе он будет общий для всех экземпляров DynamicArray 
    private int size = 0;

    public DynamicArray(int length) {
        array = new String[length];
    }
    ...
}
```

Проинициализируйте до начала использования:

```
...
Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
System.out.println("Enter array's size");
DynamicArray array = new DynamicArray(sc.nextInt());
System.out.println("Now array looks like: ");
array.state();
do {
...
```

PS: закрывайте ресурсы - вызывайте `sc.close();` после завершения работы или используйте конструкцию [try-with-resources](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/tryResourceClose.html%20try-with-resources):

```
try (Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in)) {
...
```

Comment: А разве мы должны закрывать System.in?

Comment: Закрывается не System.in, а Scanner

Comment: А разве сканер это ресурс что бы мы должны были его закрывать?

Comment: Да, при этом, если он работает с источником данных, который также реализует интерфейс `Closeable`, то и он будет закрыт (`System.in` его реализует).